# ASP.NET core - Activate a route handler only if there is no controller

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I have a generic library that manages REST API call and map them to specific files.
For do that, I wrote a Route Handler that matches the url {directory}/{filename}

The library itself works good.

Now I'd like to check if there is any controller for manage the same file.

For example, suppose we write a controller called MyDirectoryController with a GET method called MyFile.

I'd like that the route handler will process the route MyDirectory/anotherfile1, but calls the controller when the path is MyDirectory/MyFile since there is an existing controller.

How can I do that?

I am using .NET core 3.1 and this is the implementation of the route middleware:

public class RestRouteMiddleware
{

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        // I try to check for controller, but it doesn't work
        var controllerActionDescriptor = context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
        if (controllerActionDescriptor != null &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName)) return;

        // Here I manage the request (this code works, but I want to execute
        // it only if there is no controller)
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which version for your asp.net core application? 2.1 or 3.1? How you write the route handler? If possible, please post some codes whcih is related with your route handler.

Comment: Hi Brando. I edited the question adding the .NET version (3.1) and the source code of the middleware

Comment: As far as I know, the middleware is happened before the app.useendpoint this is the reason why you couldn't get the controllerActionDescriptor . Have you considered using filter instead of middleware?

Comment: I didn't. It seems a nice idea. I will give it a try as soon as possible

Comment: I looked for the filters, but they don't work. Route Handler works better because: 1 - Much easyer to extract value from url (ex: {directory}/{file}) can be read with Request.HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values.TryGetValue("directory", var out dir). 2 - Since we map a route, the handler is called when needed. In this way I can set two same handler on different route, for example for manage test and production environment. I didn't see any way to extract data in an easy way from filters, nor how to set filters only for specific routes

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using  `endpoints.MapFallbackToController` to achieve your requirement.

If the url doesn't match other route, it will match this fallbacktocontroller method.

Then you could add some logic inside this controller.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

I create a Fallback controller and its view.

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

                 });
                
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain better my goal. When the user navigate to the url http://mydir/myfile, the route middleware will show the content of myfile in mydir directory. It's ok. But if the developer write its own mydir controller with the myfile method, I want the response of http://mydir/myfile is the controller code and not the one of my middleware. The fallback is activated when the route is not matched, but in my case the url is always the same and always matches the route

Comment: But if the user doesn't write the controller action myfile, it will use the fallback method. If the user has written the action, it will use he write action method. This logic is matching your requirement. Is it right?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. In the code you put, there is a route (I suppose my route, the one that automatically manages the files) and a fallback to an Action (I suppose the action someone wrote). Since my route will always manage the file, fallback will never fire. If the fallback has to be my code, it has no controller/action and I didn't see any method that will add a fallback as function, it needs a contrller/action.

Comment: In any way I gave you two plus, since the thing you told me are interesting and maybe I can use them in the future